# Restore Permissions for IIS inetpub folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I recently changed the permissions on the inetpub folder for IIS to allow me to share the folder on the network, and since then, all of my IIS sites are failing with either 500.19, or, if I switch the application pool identity to LocalSystem, error 401.3. Based on what I’ve read about these errors, it appears that one or more components of IIS don’t have the correct permissions to access the inetpub folder. I’ve given full control permissions to every user group in the security dialogue for the folder (System, Administrators, Users, and Trusted Installer), but it hasn’t rectified the issue. I have noticed that FTP is functional, this only seems to affect my ASP.NET sites.

How can I restore the default permissions to this folder? Or is there another cause I am overlooking? Thank-you for your help.

Comment: Just use the same account your app is running with.

Comment: I’ve also tried that, but I still get error 401.3 with the following message: You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to edit the permissions on the wwwroot folder so that user IIS_IUSRS had read/write permissions. I’m guessing that I accidentally overwrote all of the permissions on the folder when I shared it on my network.

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can vote your solution as answer.